# Define a bijection between $Z^{X \cup Y}$ and $Z^X \times Z^Y$, where $X, Y \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega) $ and $X \cap Y = \emptyset$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Define a bijection between $Z^{X \cup Y}$ and $Z^X \times Z^Y$, where $X, Y \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega) $ and $X \cap Y = \emptyset$

I was given the following task to prove.

I know that we need a map $h : Z^{X \cup Y} \ \to Z^X \times Z^Y$
Firstly, we have to define a function $h(f)$ and the show that is both injective and surjective.
However, I can't define it.
I know that LHS should be $h(f)(x)(y)$. Is it correct ? What should be RHS?

Comment: Draw a picture.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $h(f)=\left(\left.f\right\rvert_X,\left.f\right\rvert_Y\right)$ seems a more reasonable candidate.

Comment: What is $\left.f\right\rvert_X,$

Comment: @RustemSadykov If $f:A\to B$ is a function and $X\subseteq A$, then $\left.f\right\rvert_X$ is the function $X\to B$ such that $\left(\left.f\right\rvert_X\right)(a)=f(a)$ for all $a\in X$. It's also known as the restriction of $f$ to $X$. The comma is not there: it's part of the pair notation $(\bullet , \diamond)$.

Comment: So you suggest to use $\left.f\right\rvert_X$ = $Z^X$ and  $\left.f\right\rvert_Y$ = $Z^Y$ ?

Comment: @RustemSadykov I suggest what I wrote, in the interpretation which is consistent with revision n°2 of your post up to the second-to-last line, included. Also, $\left.f\right\rvert_X\in Z^X$ and $\left.f\right\rvert_Y\in Z^Y$.